# Issues with File History, looking for alternative

Tags: windows-8, backup, file-history

I've been using Windows 8's *File History* feature as a backup tool for a while now, but I'm having some issues with it. I configured it to back up to a NAS drive.

In addition to backing up the internal HDD of my laptop, I also added an old RAID-less external drive to my library to ensure that File History backs up those files, too. Here's what's bugging me about File History:

- It doesn't have any form of **progress indicator**.
- I haven't finished the initial backup of my external HDD yet. I have a sneaking suspicion that File History **restarts the whole backup process** when I try to get parts of the initial external HDD backup done. I have about 3 identical copies of some files, even when their date stamps haven't changed in years.
- I have seen times where **its automatic backup doesn't start** even when the NAS had been reachable for 2 hours straight.

My current settings are as follows:

[image]

I presume that I'm better off switching to another backup solution. I'll refrain from asking for the "best" backup tool because it's against the community rules, so I'll try to be more specific about my needs:

- Support for offline Dropbox-like **instantaneous incremental backup**
- I get to **choose which folders** are backed up
- **Previous versions** of files should be accessible for up to a month, unless their file sizes make this difficult
- My NAS isn't always powered on and I use my laptop outside my home network too, so this tool should be able to **resume backups automatically** if the backup target isn't available or manually if aborted
- It should be able to back up the contents of **external HDDs** while they are connected to my laptop
- This tool should be GUI-based and be **easy-to-use**
- The **performance** of my PC should not take too much of a hit

I already have a license for [SyncBack SE](http://www.2brightsparks.com/syncback/sbse.html). As far as I know it doesn't do auto-sync, it doesn't auto-resume, it's not that user-friendly, it looks kinda yucky and it cannot handle offline backup targets that well. I've looked into [Acronis True Image 2013](http://www.acronis.eu/homecomputing/products/trueimage/) which looks very good on paper, but the reviews on Amazon are horrible.

Do you know any File History alternatives that fit these requirements?